# How to downgrade adb version on Mac. 1.0.40 to 1.0.39

Tags: macos, adb

At 1.0.40, need to be at 1.0.39 on my MacBook. Who can tell me how to downgrade. Thank you!

The reason for this is I need to connect to a server and send adb commands that is hosting my automation devices. However, the server is @ 1.0.39 and I have no (current) way to upgrade it to 1.0.40...Without having them on the same version, I cannot do what I need to do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's a fast way:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.1-darwin.zip
unzip platform-tools_r26.0.1-darwin.zip >/dev/null
cd platform-tools
./adb --version|head -1
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
```

You'll need to stash this somewhere on your path.