# How to kill adb fork-server

Tags: android, macos, macos-mojave, adb

e# Background
I updated my android studio to build 3.4 (I recall I saw a dialogue where it prompted me to delete my old android studio configuration files, some of which were like > 1GB, I happily clicked yes!).

But then suddenly my adb command stopped working:

```
adb shell
adb server version (37) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/1b/3wwzdg214cz57k2nccl_9d5c0000gn/T//adb.501.log
Server had pid: 32161
--- adb starting (pid 32161) ---
adb I 05-08 12:38:07 32161 895177 main.cpp:56] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
adb I 05-08 12:38:07 32161 895177 main.cpp:56] Version 4986621
adb I 05-08 12:38:07 32161 895177 main.cpp:56] Installed as /Users/Shared/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 05-08 12:38:07 32161 895177 main.cpp:56]
adb E 05-08 12:38:07 32161 895185 usb_osx.cpp:159] Unable to create an interface plug-in (e00002be)
adb I 05-08 12:38:07 32161 895177 auth.cpp:421] adb_auth_init...
adb I 05-08 12:38:07 32161 895177 auth.cpp:174] read_key_file '/Users/abdullah/.android/adbkey'...
adb server killed by remote request

* failed to start the daemon
error: cannot connect to the daemon
```

My current adb version is 1.4:

```
adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 4986621
Installed as /Users/Shared/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

I searched all over the place for where the 37 version is running (so that I can kill it already) but couldn't find anything. The closest thing I could find is this:

```
ps aux | grep adb
abdullah         32176   0.6  0.0  4356908   8156   ??  S    12:38PM   0:02.44 adb fork-server server
```

Which seems like a service that is running, every time I kill it though it launches again:

```
$ kill 32176
$ ps aux | grep adb
Abdullah         15806   0.7  0.0  4295468   8048   ??  S    12:44PM   0:00.05 adb fork-server server
```

## Question

How can I kill this `adb fork-server` so that I can get rid of the `37` instance of my adb?

## What I tried

I tried running `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` but got the same error

## update

I tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53748641/766570) for downgrading my adb shell to version 1.0.37
but going go the [previous list](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) of android platform tools I found out that the following versions map like so:

- platform-tools_r25.0.5-darwin.zip 1.0.39
- platform-tools_r25.0.4-darwin.zip 1.0.39
- platform-tools_r25.0.3-darwin.zip 1.0.36

**so 1.0.37 is not on the list!!!!**

## Update

I just realized that this coincided with me trying to do a screen mirroring of a tablet on my laptop, so I installed [vysor](http://www.vysor.io/). This could probably have something to do with it:
[image]

Comment: does `adb kill-server` command works ?

Comment: @VivekMishra No I tried that but didn't work, updated the *What I tried* section